# How can I use separate file for database configuration in laravel4 ?

Tags: laravel-4

I am using laravel4 for my application where I am using two databases . As first one is configured inside database.php , I want to configure my second database in a separate file .

Can you please tell me how to do this ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you configure both databases inside the database.php? Note that in this file, in the connections array, the 'mysql', 'sqlite' etc. are the keys that distinguish the available connections and not the type of the database. The type of the database is defined in the driver option of each array. So in the same way you have

```
'mysql' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'database',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => 'password',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

you can also have in the same file

```
'mysql2' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'another_database',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => 'password',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

Note that the key is mysql2 but the driver is still mysql.

You can use it like this `DB::connection('mysql2')->select(...);`

Comment: I know this one , but I have to use this separately . I got the solution for this [http://chrishayes.ca/blog/code/laravel-4-setting-utilizing-environments-environment-configuration] .Thanks.